# How to get images from image folder on real time server?

Tags: php, apache, tomcat

I have an Apache Server running on localhost and an images folder inside the
document root. In order to get all the images inside the images folder i'm using the below code

```
if (is_dir($dir)) {
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
    echo "<pre>";
        echo "filename: $file : filetype: " . filetype($dir . $file) . "\n";

    $path = "/images/$file";
    echo "<img src=".$path." alt='image' width='50px' height='50px'>";
    echo "</pre>";
    }
      closedir($dh);
  }
}
?>
```

In real time my problem is that I have a domain `https://www.example.com/` where an
images folder is kept from where i need to get all the images, I'm able to view the
images one by one by giving the url as 
`https://www.example.com/euf/assets/images/background.jpg` in the browser, that means
euf folder should be kept under the doument root of the server so if I give path as
`$dir=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."euf/assets/images/"` the above code should work ....
But the code is not working in that case. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <?php
    $dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."your/imagesfolder/path/";
    $dh = opendir($dir);
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false)
    {   

        echo "<pre>";
        echo "filename:". $file." : filetype: " . filetype($file) . "\n";

        $path = "/images/".$file;
        echo "<img src=" . $path . " alt='image' width='50px' height='50px'>";
        echo "</pre>";
    }
    closedir($dh);
```